# Insert default values in a column (access db)

Tags: ms-access, alter

How can I do for inserting a Default Value into a column of a table in Access?
I use this instruction:

```
ALTER TABLE Tabella ADD Campo Double DEFAULT 0
ALTER TABLE Tabella ADD Campo Double DEFAULT (0)
ALTER TABLE Tabella ADD Campo DEFAULT 0
ALTER TABLE Tabella ADD Campo DEFAULT (0)
ALTER TABLE Tabella ADD Campo SET DEFAULT 0
ALTER TABLE Tabella ADD Campo SET DEFAULT (0)
```

but all of these cause error. How can I do for doing it?

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243857.aspx):

> The DEFAULT statement can be executed
>   only through the Access OLE DB
>   provider and ADO. It will return an
>   error message if used through the
>   Access SQL View user interface.

Sooo... tell us more about what you're doing and how you're executing your SQL?

And why aren't you using the table designer?

Answer (score 1):

See this answer?

[SQL to add column with default value - Access 2003](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47535/sql-to-add-column-with-default-value-access-2003)

Answer (score 0):

You do not *insert* a new default value, you need to *alter* the existing one.

First switch Access to a sane SQL flavour, as in the answer linked above, then you can say:

```
alter table Tabella alter column Campo Double DEFAULT 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this typical Access function to add new fields + default values to Access tables:. The field is added if it does not already exists in the table.

```
Public Function addNewField( _
    m_tableName as string, _
    m_fieldName As String, _
    m_fieldType As Long, _      'check syntax of .createField method for values'
    m_fieldLength As Long, _    'check syntax of .createField method for values'
    Optional m_defaultValue As Variant = Null)

Dim myTable As DAO.TableDef
Dim myField As DAO.Field

On Error GoTo addNewField_error

Set myTable = currentDb.TableDefs(m_tableName)
Set myField = myTable.CreateField(m_fieldName, m_fieldType, m_fieldLength)

If Not IsNull(m_defaultValue) Then
    myField.DefaultValue = m_defaultValue
End If

myTable.Fields.Append myField

Set myTable = Nothing
Set myField = Nothing

Exit Function

addNewField_error:
If Err.Number = 3191 Or Err.Number = 3211 Then
    'The field already exists or the table is opened'
    'nothing to do but exit the function'
Else
    debug.print Err.Number & " - " & Error$
End If

End Function
```