# Creating an Access table with sql query and default bit values

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

This is my code for creating the table (in the sql view of designing a query in access)

```
 CREATE table Track (WebCompareString CHAR(255), Master INT, Child INT, 
 Merged BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, Children_Updated BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
 Deleted BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, TrackId INT PRIMARY KEY;
```

When trying to **run!** this I get the following error:
**Syntax error in CREATE TABLE statement.**

Comment: See Edit 2, it works from VBA with `CurrentProject.Connection.Execute`.

Answer (score 2):

The missing closing parenthesis is a minor problem.

The main problem is the limited support for the `DEFAULT` clause in **Access SQL**.

You need to either run the SQL command via an ADO connection:
[SQL SET DEFAULT not working in MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14057408/3820271)

or set the Access option unter Query Design to ANSI 92 compatible:
[SQL to add column with default value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47552/3820271)

**Edit**

Yes, I tested the second option (only the second one), in Access 2010 in a .accdb.
I set the option `Object Designer - Query design - SQL Server Compatible Syntax (ANSI 92) - Use in this database`. (Exact wording is guessed since I have a German Access).

Access showed a warning, then did an automatic Compact&Repair. After that I could execute the SQL from the question in a new query, only adding the closing parenthesis to the SQL string.

The Yes/No fields were created with `default value = 0`.

[image]

**Edit 2**

With the `SQL Server Compatible Syntax (ANSI 92)` option back to unchecked, I tested the first suggestion too, by simply following HansUp's code.
The following sub created the table with the default values.

```
Public Sub CreateTrackTable()

    Dim S As String

    S = "CREATE table Track (WebCompareString CHAR(255), Master INT, Child INT, " & _
        "Merged BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, Children_Updated BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, " & _
        "Deleted BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, TrackId INT PRIMARY KEY);"

    CurrentProject.Connection.Execute S

End Sub
```

So you can't run this query from the Query designer (unless you set the syntax option), but you can do it from VBA.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing parenthesis at the end.  Add a ')' right before ';'.  With that added, this statement completed successfully (with MySQL).

Answer (score 1):

You've forgotten a ')' at the end.

```
CREATE table Track (WebCompareString CHAR(255), Master INT, Child INT, 
Merged BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, Children_Updated BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
Deleted BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, TrackId INT PRIMARY KEY);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you pasted your code correct, than it seems you might have missed the closing bracket at the end.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the ending parenthesis. You should also have a look over SQL naming conventions and best practices ([Database, Table and Column Naming Conventions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662/database-table-and-column-naming-conventions)). Best of luck!

```
 CREATE table Track (
   TrackId INT PRIMARY KEY,
   WebCompareString CHAR(255),
   Master INT,
   Child INT, 
   Merged BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
   Children_Updated BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
   Deleted BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0) ;
```